# Show Right margin when resizing browser

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, media-queries

I used this to centre my main div which contains everything.

```
#main {
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

I have to make a responsive site so as i decrease the browser's size, i want the margin on the right to remain there. At the moment, my divs decrease with the size but there is no margin on the right.

Also, I don't think the main div is centred well either.

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: You can also use `margin:10% 0;` rather than using both `margin-left` and `margin-right`.

Comment: Yes but i don't want any margin on top. The code im using is working fine but the right margin disappears when i shrink the browser.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `margin:0 10%;`

Comment: Have you made sure your `html, body {` has `margin:0;`?

Comment: Ahh i figured it out... i deleted the width and height. It worked now thanks :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out now. Used this instead and pasted the same in @media

```
#main {
 margin-left: 10%;
 margin-right: 10%;
 }
```

Worked like a charm. Thanks to Titanium and Brian for the Help. Much appreciated

:D

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width: 80%; 
         position: relative; 
             left: 10%; 
            align: center; 
 background-color: red;"></div>
```